# Math book of comically convoluted proofs?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation

I remember seeing a math book that consisted entirely of proofs of banal statements using sophisticated techniques. For example, to prove $1 < 2,$ it might begin with "Consider a Hilbert space on $\mathbb{C^n}$ and a sesquilinear map ... (blah blah)" and then a few paragraphs later would be "QED" of a valid - but unnecessary - justification, purely for comic purposes. Like a "Proofs from THE BOOK" for comedians. Does anyone know the book I'm referring to?

Comment: Mathematics Made Difficult

Comment: @MarkSaving From one Mark S. to another, could you post that as an answer so this no longer appears unanswered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mathematics Made Difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Made_Difficult) by Carl Linderholm is the book you’re looking for. I actually found reading it was quite helpful. Its proof of the commutative property of addition for $\mathbb{N}$ is quite nice, for example.

Comment: Yes, I think most people would be skeptical if I told them I could be laughing out loud while learning abstract mathematics.

Comment: Seems like the perfect book for the coming festive season. Linderholm dedicates it to [Clement V. Durell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._V._Durell) "without whom this book would not have been necessary." According to Wikipedia, Durell's books were hugely successful in schools of the English speaking world. This does not sound like Durell is a target of Linderholm's satire, quite the contrary. But why would Linderholm's book be *not necessary* without Durell?